# How to use ng-repeat for dynamic variables?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have my scope variables as, `$scope.result1`, `$scope.result2`, `$scope.result3` etc., in my controller. How can I implement some common ng-repeat for the result. So, I want to have something like this in my html script.

```
<div ng-repeat="i in [] | range:3"> // I have filter "range" declared, so no problem with this loop.
  {{$index}}
  <div ng-repeat='result in result$index'>
     {{result}}
  </div>
</div>
```

But I am unable to implement this. Can I do something like this in any means?

Comment: put your results in to an array

Answer (score 0):

For my work I write this:

.html

```
<div ng-repeat="i in [] | range:3">
   <div ng-init="test($index)">
      <div ng-repeat="x in result[$index]">
        {{result}}
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

--- .js

```
$scope.test = function (index) {
...
   $parse('result['+index+']').assign($scope, response);

}
```